# JS: Path parse to JSON fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

i have 2 canvases and i´m drawing on one of them.
Then i want to parse path from canvas one and paste in to canvas two.
How can i parse path from canvas one to JSON format in fabric.js ?
Thank you for all advices!

Comment: welcome to SO; please always post a snippet of code that can be used to reproduce your problem, explaining the result you get and the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

From the fabric.js docs the canvas can be [serialized](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#serialization) and [deserialized](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#deserialization):

```
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var canvasJSON = JSON.stringify(canvas1);

var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas();
canvas2.loadFromJSON(canvasJSON)
```